# groovy-devel, hydro-devel, different git branches architecture question

Tags: ros, devel, git

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this is a really general question about git and branches and i could put it somewhere else (stackoverflow) but I would like to know for the developers that are using *hydro-devel* and *groovy-devel* (for example) how do you synchronize changes one branch and another. Do you use something like **cherry-picking** to select exactly what files to synchronize? Can you even use the cherry-picking for **merging**??? So, what's the usual standard that you use? the question is mainly because when you develop something for some branch and you want to put that utility to the other branch, (i think) you won't do rebase, you will try to merge only some specific files which are not going to mess up some others.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174369/groovy-devel,-hydro-devel,-different-git-branches-architecture-question/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-06-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the standard way to port code from one development branch to another is to use cherry-pick. Well constructed commits will usually cherry-pick betwen branches relatively easily.

You cannot use merge unless you want all changes. Generally merging is only done to bring feature branches/pull-requests into a development branch and never for crossing between forked development branches.

rebase is super powerful and can be used in many ways. However if the content is already available to others in a public branch it should not be used. It's really for cleaning up local branches/development before pushing content.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There should be many people in ROS community who can explain more thoroughly, but here's what I know:

- To synchronize branches, I think `git merge` and `git rebase` (use either one depending on the purpose) is generally preferred to `git cherry-pick` ([ref. from stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229301/git-cherry-pick-says-38c74d-is-a-merge-but-no-m-option-was-given)). `cherry-pick` is useful particularly when you want to sync the specific commits.
- In ROS, branching per distro seems to be a common practice, e.g. `{ groovy, hydro, indigo }-devel` as you pointed out. Note, however, that you may create a branch for a new ROS distro ONLY when there's a necessity; for instance, while the latest ROS distro is hydro, the latest development branch of [rqt_common_plugins](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins) remains `groovy-devel` since all the code there is expected to run on both distributions and thus it reduces the maintainer's effort. This kind of branching policy can vary depending on repositories (and for `rqt`, it's [documented here](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt#Github_policy_for_rqt_plugins)).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2